# Cannot find the expected secondary table while generating classes automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I am using intellij and new to hibernate. While generating class for branch table and executing I get an exception:

- The branch table contains the following columns: `id, institute_id,
  street_id, name`.
  `id` is a foreign key to super table (I have 2 table that share the same id sequence).
  `institute_id` is a foreign key to institute table.
  `street_id` is a foreign key to street table.
- The Branch class that created by intellij is:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Branch {
   private long id;

   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
   @Id
   public long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   private long instituteId;

   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "institute_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
   @Basic
   public long getInstituteId() {
      return instituteId;
   }

   public void setInstituteId(long instituteId) {
      this.instituteId = instituteId;
   }

   private long streetId;

   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "street_id", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
   @Basic
   public long getStreetId() {
      return streetId;
   }

   public void setStreetId(long streetId) {
      this.streetId = streetId;
   }

   private String name;

   @javax.persistence.Column(name = "name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 50, precision = 0)
   @Basic
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      Branch branch = (Branch) o;

      if (id != branch.id) return false;
      if (instituteId != branch.instituteId) return false;
      if (streetId != branch.streetId) return false;
      if (name != null ? !name.equals(branch.name) : branch.name != null) return false;

      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
      result = 31 * result + (int) (instituteId ^ (instituteId >>> 32));
      result = 31 * result + (int) (streetId ^ (streetId >>> 32));
      result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
   }

   private Institute instituteByInstituteId;

   @ManyToOne
   public
   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "institute_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, table = "branch")
   Institute getInstituteByInstituteId() {
      return instituteByInstituteId;
   }

   public void setInstituteByInstituteId(Institute instituteByInstituteId) {
      this.instituteByInstituteId = instituteByInstituteId;
   }

   private Street streetByStreetId;

   @ManyToOne
   public
   @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "street_id", referencedColumnName = "id", table = "branch")
   Street getStreetByStreetId() {
      return streetByStreetId;
   }

   public void setStreetByStreetId(Street streetByStreetId) {
      this.streetByStreetId = streetByStreetId;
   }
  }
  ```
- This is the code I execute (intellij created this automatically):

  ```
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
      final Session session = getSession();
      try {
          System.out.println("querying all the managed entities...");
          final Map metadataMap = session.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
          for (Object key : metadataMap.keySet()) {
              final ClassMetadata classMetadata = (ClassMetadata) metadataMap.get(key);
              final String entityName = classMetadata.getEntityName();
              final Query query = session.createQuery("from " + entityName);
              System.out.println("executing: " + query.getQueryString());
              for (Object o : query.list()) {
                  System.out.println("  " + o);
              }
          }
      } finally {
          session.close();
      }
  }
  ```
- I got the following exception:

  ```
  org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary table: no branch available for GreenWheels.Data.Entities.Branch
  ```

**UPDATE**
When I generated entities with xml per entity, it created the following xml for branch and now it works. How is that?..

```
Branch.nbm.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="GreenWheels.Data.Entities.Branch" table="branch" catalog="greenwheels">
        <id name="id">
            <column name="id" sql-type="bigint" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </id>
        <property name="instituteId">
            <column name="institute_id" sql-type="bigint" length="19" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="streetId">
            <column name="street_id" sql-type="bigint" length="19"/>
        </property>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" sql-type="varchar" length="50" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="instituteByInstituteId" class="GreenWheels.Data.Entities.Institute">
            <column name="institute_id" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="streetByStreetId" class="GreenWheels.Data.Entities.Street">
            <column name="street_id"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated class is incorrect. I don't know exactly what the message means, but what's sure is that the entity is not mapped correctly: the `institute_id` is mapped twice: once as a `Column` and once as a `JoinColumn`. Same for `streetId`. It also adds attributes which are not needed. Here's how the class should look like:

```
@Entity
public class Branch {
 private long id;

 @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 19, precision = 0)
 @Id
 public long getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 private String name;

 @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 private Institute institute;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "institute_id", nullable = false)
 public Institute getInstitute() {
    return institute;
 }

 public void setInstitute(Institute institute) {
    this.institute = institute;
 }

 private Street street;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "street_id")
 public Street getStreet() {
    return street;
 }

 public void setStreet(Street street) {
    this.street = street;
 }
}
```

My guess is that the error is called by the `table = "branch"` attributes of the JoinColumn annotations.

Comment: This doesn;t work.. I still get this exception. Please see update.

Comment: This solution worked for me. When mapping a ManyToOne relationship like this, I had an `@Column` entry for the foreign key in addition to the `@JoinColumn` entry. I simply removed the `@Column` as it was redundant and it worked!